# launch other application in android/IOS devices with Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I try to launch in Cordova(Phonegap) Skype application on all devices (Android, IOS, Windows).

I have compiled the following function, but works only on the Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (Android). On many other mobile devices does'nt work the function. Even on iPhone and iPad not.

The function:

```
    function launchSkype() {
    var scheme;

    if (device.platform === 'iOS') {
        scheme = 'skype://';
    } else if (device.platform === 'Android') {
        scheme = 'com.skype.raider';
    } else if (device.platform === 'wp') {
        scheme = 'skype:';
    } else if (device.platform === 'windows8') {
        scheme = 'skype:';
    }

    navigator.startApp.check(scheme, function(message) { /* success */
        navigator.startApp.start(scheme, function(message) {
        }, function(error) { /* error */
            alert("Skype could not be started!");
        });
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Skype is not installed!");
    });
}
```

I also get no error messages. In Cordova I have installed the following additional plugin :
org.apache.cordova.device

com.lampa.startapp.startApp

Could someone make a suggestion, perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Are you sure you call the function `launchSkype` from within `deviceReady`?

Comment: that is my call:

`<button onclick="launchSkype()" id="sykpeButton" class="button">
 <i class="ion-social-skype"></i> <br> 
</button>`

Comment: are you using separate files for your angular controllers and modules? if so you need to declare your dependencies in each one. If you do not then you can have this issue where plug ins do not work, but also throw no errors.

Comment: How can i declare the dependencies in each one? Thanks

Comment: @Ramosta is this fixed ? I too having same issue